# Altering JSON array using python

Tags: python, json

This is the way reading from a .json file on ubuntu terminal:

```
python -c "import json;print json.loads(open('json_file.json', 'r').read())['foo']['bar']"
```

What I'd like to do is altering the JSON file, adding new objects and arrays. So how to do this in python?

json_file.json:

```
{
    "data1" :
    [
        {
            "unit" : "Unit_1",
            "value" : "20"
        },
        {
            "unit" : "Unit_2",
            "value" : "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You read it in, modify it, and write it back. It'd be easier if you didn't cram all of your Python code into one line.

Comment: @Blender found the code from google. My python knowledge is so limited. I'd like to know how to modify .json files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, create a new python file.

```
import json

data = json.loads(open('json_file.json', 'r').read())
```

The data is then just a bunch of nested dictionaries and lists.

You can modify it the same way you would modify any python dictionary and list; it shouldn't be hard to find a resource on this as it is one of the most basic python functionalities.  You can find a complete reference at the [**official python documentation**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), and if you are familiar with arrays/lists and associative arrays/hashes in any language, this should be enough to get you going.  If it's not, you can probably find a tutorial and if that doesn't help, if you are able to create a well-formed specific question then you could ask it here.

once you are done, you can put everything back into json:

```
print json.dumps(data)
```

For more information on how to customize the output, and about the `json` module overall, see the [**documentation**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).